# Filter pandas dataframe using a single character of a string column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, slice

In the following dataframe, "day" is a string column for a 7-character binary code to specify whether or not an event occurs on a particular day. The first character indicates whether or not the event occurs on Monday, and final character indicates whether the event occurs on Sunday.

For example:

```
    event  day
 0  A      1000010
 1  B      1010100
 2  C      0100010
 3  D      0000011
```

Event A occurs on Monday and Saturday, event B occurs on Monday, Wednesday and Friday, and event D occurs on Saturday and Sunday.

Question: How can I filter a dataframe using a specific character of the "day" column? For example, if I want to show all rows for events on Saturday, something like `day[5]=="1"` should output rows 2 and 3 (containing events "C" and "D").

I've tried various combinations such as `df.loc[(df['day'][5]=="1")]` based on other examples but they don't work for filtering by a single character of a string.

(I know it's unconventional but the system has served me well using Bash scripts with Awk; just trying to develop it further in Python with Pandas).

Comment: so, `day` has a string dtype?

Comment: yes, the column is initialised as a string in pd.read_csv( ... dtype={'day':'str'} ... )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have strings, you can use slicing and comparison to `'1'`:

```
day = 0
df[df['day'].str[day].eq('1')]    # if Monday = 0
# or
day = 1
df[df['day'].str[day-1].eq('1')]  # if Monday = 1
```

output:

```
  event      day
0     A  1000010
1     B  1010100
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the string to dataframe each column for one week day

```
s = df.day.apply(lambda x : pd.Series(list(x)))


df[s[0]=='1']
```

Answer (score 1):

you could create a column for each day:

```
import pandas as pd

df = {'event': ['A','B','C','D'], 'day': ['1000010','1010100','0100010','0000011']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=df)
df

df['Mon'] = df['day'].astype(str).str[0]
df['Tue'] = df['day'].astype(str).str[1]
df['Wed'] = df['day'].astype(str).str[2]
df['Thu'] = df['day'].astype(str).str[3]
df['Fri'] = df['day'].astype(str).str[4]
df['Sat'] = df['day'].astype(str).str[5]
df['Sun'] = df['day'].astype(str).str[6]

print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks. That was what I did in an earlier CLI version in Bash with Awk. It was a good enough solution until screenspace became more important, and I merged the variables to save space in a GUI version. Using a single variable for day of week also makes the code more compact, in that I only need to use `day_number = datetime.today().weekday()` to slice the dataframe with the one variable (using `df[df['day'].str[day_number].eq('1')]` from the solution I've selected) only once rather than a separate test for each day.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.for check 1 in 2nd index.

```
index = 1
df.loc[(df['day'].str[index]=="1")
```

output is

```
  event      day
2     C  0100010
```